# The plugins.php page cannot be found

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress and want to add a plugin. But when I press the 【plugin】 button, it says it doesn't find the page (url=xxxx.com/wp-admin/plugins.php).

```
We’re sorry but the page is not existed or deleted by the administrator. Perhaps searching can help.
```

But the plugins.php file indeed exists in the wp-admin folder (authority=755).
If I change it to 777, the xxxx.com/wp-admin/plugins.php page will show:

```
Internal Server Error

File "/home/enjoyrea/domains/fding.xyz/public_html/wp-admin/plugins.php" is writeable by group
```

This page (xxxx.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php) doesn't work either.

But this (xxxx.com//wp-admin/plugin-editor.php) is ok.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: is there no plugin in your site ?

Comment: re-install or update your WordPress site and try again. Seems like you are missing some files.

Comment: The Suggestion from @Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim is quite ideal here. However, if you have already done a lot in your Project, you can easily download a new copy of WP. Copy the core Files/Folders ***wp-admin & wp-includes*** over to your old installation. **It is important to download the same version as the one you have in your current installation.**

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Yes, there are three plugins I installed before. It was ok at that time. I don't know what happened.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim The update page【wp-admin/update-core.php】cannot be found either... But other buttons are ok, e.g. 【wp-admin/users.php】, 【wp-admin/tools.php】,【wp-admin/themes.php】.

Comment: then it should not show this error, go to directory manually check if the file is really not present and if yes, download wordpress of same version you are using and replace the wp-admin and wp-includes folder, but more than that you need to know how it happened if there some script running with out your knowledge, then you may need to do something more but after knowing it correctly .

Comment: @Poiz I just tried what you said and I covered the old files in those 2 folders, but the /plugins.php page still cannot be found...

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu The files are there (644). I re-download them and change them to 755. But the /plugins.php page still cannot be found. ........

Comment: And the plugins themselves are still working. I can still see the latex formula showing.

Comment: if other plugins are working then it should be okay .can you tell me which plugin you want to install ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/   . I have already uploaded it to the wp-content/plugins folder. I don't know how to activate it now...

Comment: Can you create a blank plugin and try to install and active that ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu @.@ I don't know how to do this without the plugins--activate button...

Comment: check https://gist.github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/6d067b9b4a212859bec1052e8bb457d2 now keep plugin name blank-test-plugin and file name blank-test-plugin.php .so it will be plugins/blank-test-plugin/blank-test-plugin.php  use it

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Oh, thank you! I can create the folder and the file plugins/blank-test-plugin/blank-test-plugin.php. But it is inactive right now. How to activate it ?

Comment: sorry, I was taking your question wrongly. ok, better will be removing all plugins temporarily and try to access wp-admin/plugins and let me know status

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu still cannot find the plugins.php page, and the plugins are disabled~

Comment: then please try adding plugins.php page manually in its respective folder and test it , there must be something really wired how the plugins.php file will be deleted automatically ??

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I add it. But no use. I update my question, please see it ~~ Thank you for your kindness :)

Comment: contact your hosting provider may be they can guide you better or can give more detail about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with this. (Wordpress version - 4.7)

In my solution was change PHP server version to 5.5.32 (ealier was 5.2) and change memory_limit to 256 - because wordfence plugin needed.

This works for me. Maybe will help for others.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running PHP 7.x.  I also had to update memory limit to 256M in php.ini.  Once I did this, the plugins admin page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ssl on your page?
Maybe you are redirected to "https ://xxxx.com/wp-admin/plugins.php" while you page work on http only

Answer (score 0):

Non of the answers worked for me. I solved by adding the 404 php file to /wp-admin/.htaccess file.

There was an autogenerated FileMatch like:

```
<FilesMatch '^(index.php|auto_seo.php|wp-blog-header.php|...)$'>
```

So I added the files that are returning a 404 to that file match and it works.

Don't know if this could be a valid solution to the problem.